# Python - Combine array of indices with vector of values to get array of values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In Python, say I have a 2D array of indices `a=array([1,3],[0,0])` and a 1D array of the values corresponding to those indices: `u=array([7.7, 4.2, 5.1, 8.7, 2.2])`.  I want to combine `a` with `u` to get:

`result = array([[4.2, 8.7],[7.7,7.7])`

I could do this with a list comprehension, but is there a more elegant way? Note that `len(u)` might be larger than the maximum value of `a`.

Comment: ........ `u[a]`?

Comment: Of course! Thanks!

Comment: @Divakar "OK that's the answer, now I need 9 more characters to post the comment." *leans on period key*

Comment: @DanielF Those key presses also work as expression of sigh

Comment: @Divakar always the efficient one